# Selenium/Xpath select option containing text

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, jasmine

For one of my tests I am trying to select an option that contains the text "Current"

The select dropdown looks like so:

```
<select name="lead" class="wide">
<option value="">-- Select a lead --</option>
<option value="5066689">Current Lead: L5066689 (kitchens) Created: '27/08/2021 11:10:53'</option>
<option value="5066671"> L5066671 (kitchens) Created: '27/08/2021 09:56:10'</option></select>
```

What I'm trying is using this function:

```
const chooseCurrentLeadToSaveAgainst = async () => {
    await pageHelpers.waitForSelectorAndClick(selectors.leadDropdown);
    await logger.logScreenshot();
    await pageHelpers.waitForSelectorAndClick(selectors.currentLead);
};
```

The leadDropdown selector is:

```
leadDropdown: 'select.wide',
```

This works and the test will click on the select box to open it up, I am then attempting to try click on the option that contains the the text 'Current' through the selector currentLead:

```
 currentLead: 'option[(contains(text(),\'Current\')]',
```

With this selector, however, it's failing to find it and can't click on it, where am I going wrong with this selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those back slashes does not look good. use `//` initially to select the current node, see below :-

```
//option[(contains(text(),'Current')]
```

also if you are confident that this value will not change, `5066689` try to use value attribute.

**Update :**

```
driver.click('select.wide').click('select.wide option:nth-child(1)')
```

Comment: this unfortunately still does not work and this test will cover quite a few different plans so the value will change

Comment: What is the final goal, just to select an option from this drop down right ?

Comment: yes, well I'm wanting it to select the one that has the text "Current Lead"